# Why doesn't transpose change the iteration order of an array

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, transpose

I was trying to iterate a matrix column by column. But the result of iteration of the transpose of that matrix is same as the that of the original matrix. I am wondering why that is.

Here is my code:

```
mat1=np.fromfunction(add2,(3,4),dtype=float)
print([x for x in np.nditer(mat1)])
```

which is same as

```
m2=np.transpose(mat1)
print([x for x in np.nditer(m2)])
```

The print result for the first part is:

```
[array(0.), array(1.), array(2.), array(3.), array(1.), array(2.), array(3.), array(4.), array(2.), array(3.), array(4.), array(5.)]
```

and the result for the second part is:

```
[array(0.), array(1.), array(2.), array(3.), array(1.), array(2.), array(3.), array(4.), array(2.), array(3.), array(4.), array(5.)]
```

Comment: What do you mean? You are transposing in both examples.  The only difference is in one, you store the result of the transpose in a variable.

Comment: Don't use `nditer`, or atleast read up on its use of `order`.  Use `np.ravel(mat1, order=...)` (experiment with different orders).  (`nditer` it too complex (and slow) for this task)

Comment: `transpose` does not actually change the order of elements in the underlying databuffer.  It changes `shape` and `strides`, but otherwise is a `view`.

Comment: Why didn't you show the results of the `print`? Are you expecting us to perform the print in our heads (or at least in a python session of our own)?

Comment: I just uploaded the print result.